# Catching up after living off expertise in an outdated technology

Tags: career-development, career-switch, training

A friend of mine is employed at company A *(10.000+ employees)* as an expert in technology T, which is a core component of their day-to-day operations. Technology T is somewhat outdated, and new projects have been developed on technology U instead. Replacement rate is slow and T still accounts for 60-70% of operations.

The company has initiated a large-scale project to phase out T entirely and replace all the running components with U. My friend, along with other experts in the field, is part of that project. He fears that once it is completed, his position might be eliminated, and rumors of  layoffs are already springing up. He came to realize that **he has screwed up by not keeping up with current technologies**, and is now fighting an uphill battle.

I already told him that to remain valuable to the company, he should expand his skillset to match other needs, and for the time being becoming fluent in U seems the most direct route. **What other steps can he undertake to maximize his chances to keep a job at his current company ?** He likes the place and insists on staying with them, in spite of my suggestion that he updates his resume and tries to secure another job promptly - if the rumors come true, the local job market may soon be saturated with specialists in T.

<sub>FWIW, this is not a country with at-will employment, and while
companies may not legally terminate someone without cause, they
usually get creative in order to downsize.</sub>

Comment: I think that's too broad for us to answer. Improve skills generally, including soft skills such as leadership and collaboration. Look at where the company is going and try to help lead them there.

Comment: Is there any chance of moving upwards rather than just keeping status quo in a new technology? This is one route that many people have taken, because their knowledge of the company and overview is valuable.

Comment: I think you already have your answer: he should become fluent in U. I'm assuming he is already well-regarded in the workplace, and am therefore assuming that a lack of fluency in U is the only reason he would be let go.

Comment: who's going to be doing the T to U migration? surely ideally, people will need to be fluent in T (and U), so your friend has a chance to learn U during the migration.

Comment: More often than not in this scenario, the company fails to actually get rid of T.  There's a good chance they will still be using T when your friend retires...

Comment: Migrating from T to U will probably take a long time, he has way enough time to learn about U.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The company has initiated a large-scale project to phase out T
>   entirely and replace all the running components with U. My friend,
>   along with other experts in the field, is part of that project.

Updating his resume and getting out before everyone else might work in the short term - but T will probably also be(come) legacy at any new place. Any long-term solution involves becoming proficient in U.

Depending on the role your friend has in the project, it could be a great opportunity for learning skill U in the context of T.

If his role is merely explaining T to others who perform the actual conversion to U, he could seek to change that role. In any transitional phase, intermediates are often needed along the way.

Comment: This, exactly. Also, in a transition period, the people most valuable are those who know the old _and_ the new technology. So if the friend learns U, he may be more valuable than someone who is fluent in U but does not know T.

Answer (score 1):

> The company has initiated a large-scale project to phase out T entirely and replace all the running components with U. My friend, along with other experts in the field, is part of that project.

This is key, he is involved at least somewhat with U, even if he's only replacing components.

- While doing this, learn as much as possible about U, read manuals, interrogate U experts, and so on
- Ask the manager for training on U, express desire to become a U expert, they may or may not welcome that
- This replacement process he's working on now can arguably *count as "experience with U"* on resumes and so on. He doesn't want to look for a job now, but if the time comes, it helps to be able to paint yourself as experienced with U already (also for internal vacancies)